# IOS 7: Transparent Viewcontroller Background over another Viewcontroller with different Orientation behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiviewcontroller, transparent

I have 2 ViewControllers (IOS7) and I want to show the second one over the first one with a transparent background and different orientation behaviour.

For Example: Pressing a button on the first ViewController will bring up the second ViewController but the first one will still be visible on the background in the transparent areas of the second ViewController.
If I rotate the phone only the second ViewController will rotate while the first one (the one in the background) stays in the same orientation.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: on your Attributes inspector setup the alpha to -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can present the second ViewController modally on the first on, with the first one having a **modalPresentationStyle** of type **UIModalPresentationCurrentContext**.

If your first ViewController is embedded in a ContainerViewController like UINavigationController, you have to set the modalPresentationStyle on that one and need to present the second ViewController on it.

In your first ViewController, it would look like:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:[SecondViewController new] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You also have to configure/implement your desired behavior for the supported interface orientations, of course. For example by overriding *supportedInterfaceOrientations()* in the second ViewController, like so:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: It worked!!!
thank you very much for your help!!!!!
The key is to use UIModalPresentationCurrentContext as the presentationStyle =D