# Translucent Viewcontroller over another Viewcontroller with different Orientation behaviour

Tags: objective-c, ios7, orientation, transparency, ios8

For an app targeted at both iOS 7 and iOS 8, I'm using two ViewControllers which should have the following characteristics:

- ViewController 1 (VC1) is in Portrait Mode
- VC1 created ViewController 2 (VC2) which is in Landscape mode
- VC2 has a translucent background so that VC1's contents are visible

I've referred to [IOS 7: Transparent Viewcontroller Background over another Viewcontroller with different Orientation behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348324/ios-7-transparent-viewcontroller-background-over-another-viewcontroller-with-di) but the solution provided does not work. On iOS 8, I can either get landscape orientation or transparency for VC2 but not both

Here's what I'm doing:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
label.text = @" I'M VC1";

[self.view addSubview:label];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    LandscapeViewController* lvc = [[LandscapeViewController alloc] init];

    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

    //Uncomment this line for transparency but loses orientation
    //lvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

    [self presentViewController:lvc animated:YES completion:nil];

});
```

Any idea what's wrong and how can I make it work?